# How to iterate through UnqLite collection and extract data

Tags: python, in-memory-database, unqlite

```
db = UnQLite('test.db')
data = db.collection('data')
print(data.fetch(0))
```

This works.

Now, how do I fetch each record and extract the necessary fields from it?

I am looking for something like

```
db = UnQLite('test.db')
data = db.collection('data')
for i in range(data.size()???)
print(data.fetch(i))
```

There isn't any size() method on the collection. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A collection is itself iterable:

```
for record in data:
    # use record
    # to save changes:
    data.update(record['__id'], record)
data.reset_cursor() # if you want to iterate again
```

Answer (score -1):

**len**() Return the number of records in the database.

Warning: This method calculates the lengthy by iterating and counting every record. At the time of writing, there is no C API for calculating the size of the database.

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
      print data[i]
```